# generate random number from given set of numbers in ios

Tags: ios, random

i want to generate random number from given set of numbers.

if given set of numbers are "2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 13 and 15" then random number must be generates from the above described number.

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *arrNumbers = @[@2, @4, @7, @9, @13, @15];
NSLog(@"%d",[[arrNumbers objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(arrNumbers.count)] intValue]);
```

Comment: why use `NSMutableArray` not C array...

Comment: @BryanChen yes we can at that time i don't remember about the C array i think thats better and easy

Comment: not sure how you define "better and easy"... it have more code and slower

Comment: Don't use `objectAtIndex:arc4random()%arrNumbers.count`, there is a bias and it is even easier to use `arc4random_uniform(arrNumbers.);` which has no bias. – Zaph 18 secs ago edit –  Zaph just now   edit

Comment: @BryanChen i mean to say  C array is better and slower.

Comment: You really need something to convert the `NSNumber` to an int: `u_int32_t index = arc4random_uniform((int)(arrNumbers.count));` `NSLog(@"%d", [arrNumbers[index] intValue]);`

Answer (score 3):

try this..

```
- (int)randomNumber
{
    int arr[7] = {2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 13, 15};
    return arr[rand()%7];
}
```

Update :

```
- (int)randomNumber
{
    int arr[7] = {2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 13, 15};
    return arr[arc4random_uniform(7)];
}
```

Comment: Do not use `rand`, it is not really random and with the same seed (or none) will produce the same sequence each tie the program is run.

Answer (score 2):

`arc4random_uniform()` will provide a random integer in the needed range without any bias and no seeding is needed.

```
- (int)randomNumber {
    int arr[7] = {2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 13, 15};
    int index = arc4random_uniform(7);
    return arr[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arc4random() % countOfYourSet;
```

Comment: Don't use `arc4random() % countOfYourSet;`, there is a bias and it is even easier to use `arc4random_uniform(countOfYourSet);` which has no bias.